Docker logs at SQL Server instance
Currently trying to start an instance of SQL Server 2022 with Docker but each time I try it fails and inspecting with docker logs gives me a long and cryptic log. I couldn't be more specific for the question as I have to provide a log file that I am unable to read properly so i am providing this screenshot.
enter image description here
version: '3.8'

services:
  sqlserver_container:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    container_name: sqlserver_instance
    ports:
      - "1434:1434"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=YourStrong!Passw0rd
    volumes:
      - my_sqlserver_data:/data/db
volumes:
  my_sqlserver_data:

I tried changing the volume name but it didn't make a difference. I can spin other containers (ex. MongoDB), so I don't know what's wrong with it. Also port 1433 is free to listen.

Aside... the SA_PASSWORD environment variable is deprecated. As per the mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation it has been MSQL_SA_PASSWORD for some time already.

Are you sure you're not mapping the volume to /var/opt/mssql? Overriding that folder in the image would cause some of the expected files and folders to be missing.

Have you looked at the contents of the log file in /var/opt/mssql/log in the container at all?
